# HttpService from @nestjs/axios doesn't work on node 18

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I have this code on a service of NestJS

```
import { HttpException, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { HttpService } from '@nestjs/axios';
import { lastValueFrom, catchError, map } from 'rxjs';
import { AdjuntoService } from '../adjunto/adjunto.service';
import { HtmlPdfBodyPost, HtmlPdfBodyQueryPost } from 'src/dtos/aux.dto';
import { CierreContableService } from '../cierre_contable/cierre_contable.service';

@Injectable()
export class FilesService {
  constructor(
    private readonly httpService: HttpService,
    private readonly adjunto: AdjuntoService,
    private readonly cierreContable: CierreContableService,
  ) {}

  async htmlToPdf(query: HtmlPdfBodyQueryPost, body: HtmlPdfBodyPost) {
    const FormData = require('form-data');
    const bodyFormData: FormData = new FormData();

    for (const key in body) {
      bodyFormData.append(key, body[key]);
    }

    const data = await lastValueFrom(
      this.httpService
        .post(process.env.PYPDF.concat('html_pdf'), bodyFormData)
        .pipe(
          map((resp) => resp.data),
          map((data_) => data_),
          catchError((e) => {
            throw new HttpException(e.response.data, e.response.status);
          }),
        ),
    );

    return { data };
  }
}
```

If I execute it with node 16 it works fine, but with node 18, I get this error:

**Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')**

Comment: The code line about the error will help. What you can do: Log each "data" and show where the problem is. `map((resp) => resp.data),` -> log the response to see what goes wrong.

Comment: There's no response because it's not even doing the request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was related to https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/3821

Finally I solved it by doing suggested here
https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/3821#issuecomment-1413727575:

```
import { setDefaultResultOrder } from "dns";
setDefaultResultOrder("ipv4first");
```